# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

My app was working perfectly before until this morning when I ran my code in android studio and it crashed, I checked logcat and it pointed to these two places

first is in the `MainActivity.java` in the `onStart`

```
  mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.main_app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("ChatPlus");


    BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    loadFragment(new RequestFragment());


    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        mUserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

    }
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart(); //crashes here
    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if (currentUser == null) {
        sendtostart();
    } else {
        mUserRef.child("online").setValue("true");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if (currentUser != null) {
        mUserRef.child("online").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
    }
}
```

second place is in my `RequestFragment`

```
 mMainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_request, container, false);

    mRequestList = (RecyclerView) mMainView.findViewById(R.id.request_list);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mCurrent_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid(); //at this line


    mRequestDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friend_req").child(mCurrent_user_id);
    mRequestDatabase.keepSynced(true);
    mUsersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    mUsersDatabase.keepSynced(true);
```

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: if `mAuth.getCurrentUser()` returns null it means that you are not longer signed-in. As @TamirAbutbul pointed out you must be careful with null pointer exception and always check them. Moreover you must pay attention and always check if your current user is singed in or not.